# Selenium returns unknownProtocolFound error

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to download an APK file from [this GooglePlay direct link generator][1] using Firefox *Webdriver*, *Selenium* and *Python*.

The problem is that, when Selenium is trying to get the home page, it crashes with the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ghasemi/PycharmProjects/phorcys_watcher/main.py
http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=com.instagram.android
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ghasemi/PycharmProjects/phorcys_watcher/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    content = google_play_download("com.instagram.android")
  File "/home/ghasemi/PycharmProjects/phorcys_watcher/collector.py", line 20, in google_play_download
    browser.get("https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=" + app_page_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=unknownProtocolFound&u=httpss%3A//www.adnetworkperformance.com/script/java.php%3Foption%3Drotateur%26r%3D411313%26treqn%3D1025813717%26runauction%3D1%26crr%3D168ce9d76b1a6695b12e%2CwcwHrNzGnshFns2PnM3bbcwGW8xLz-mNycwuvZjurZja3MzJfMxG_9xMX4wYns7a2YxHvshBL9xe3shbjN2J7umN6umNm-mNuN2czNw723956800778f24b2db6%26rtid%3D595b6ecb8ac19%26cbrandom%3D0.7519066097934798%26cbtitle%3DAPK%2520Downloader%2520%255BLatest%255D%2520Download%2520Directly%2520%257C%2520Chrome%2520Extension%2520v3%2520%28Evozi%2520Official%29%26cbiframe%3D0%26cbWidth%3D1280%26cbHeight%3D717%26cbdescription%3DDownload%2520APKs%2520Directly%2520From%2520Google%2520Play%2520To%2520Your%2520Computer%2520With%2520APK%2520Downloader%2520Extension%2520For%2520Google%2520Chrome%26cbkeywords%3D%26cbref%3D&c=&f=regular&d=Firefox%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20know%20how%20to%20open%20this%20address%2C%20because%20one%20of%20the%20following%20protocols%20%28httpss%29%20isn%E2%80%99t%20associated%20with%20any%20program%20or%20is%20not%20allowed%20in%20this%20context.
```

The exception throws on this line:
    browser.get("https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=com.instagram.android")

As you see above, the origin of this error is a wrong link in the page that selenium is trying to download it. I found the frame that cause this error:

```
<iframe width="468" height="60" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="border: medium none; padding: 0; margin: 0;" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin" id="595b6e88086f8" frameborder="0" src="httpss://www.adnetworkperformance.com/script/java.php?option=rotateur&amp;r=411313&amp;treqn=501505383&amp;runauction=1&amp;crr=fc25086f39dc3c58bbdbGJTJyVGZh9Gbud3bk1yawFmRyUSbvNmLpp3b2VmLzBHchZkMlYkMlE0MlMHc0RHa2dfe473f7c304fd8fb65&amp;rtid=595b6e88086f8&amp;cbrandom=0.6676681852413189&amp;cbtitle=APK%20Downloader%20%5BLatest%5D%20Download%20Directly%20%7C%20Chrome%20Extension%20v3%20(Evozi%20Official)&amp;cbiframe=0&amp;cbWidth=1522&amp;cbHeight=741&amp;cbdescription=Download%20APKs%20Directly%20From%20Google%20Play%20To%20Your%20Computer%20With%20APK%20Downloader%20Extension%20For%20Google%20Chrome&amp;cbkeywords=&amp;cbref=" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

As you can see, the webpage developer put `httpss` instead of `https` wrongly (twice!).

How can I handle this problem?

**Update:**

My scraper:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

def google_play_download(app_page_id):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=" + app_page_id)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block").click()
    apk_link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-success.btn-block").get_attribute('href')
    browser.quit()
    for rnd in range(5):
        resp = requests.get(apk_link)
        if resp.headers['Content-Length'] == str(len(resp.content)):
            return resp.content


if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = google_play_download("com.instagram.android")
    f = open('./file', 'wb')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()

  [1]: https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be a url-parsing funktion, that you call on each url before driver.get(url)

```
def url_parser(url):
    if 'httpss' in url:
        url = url.replace('httpss','https')
    return url
```

You'd then use it like so

```
url = url_parser(url)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: The driver itself tries to get the buggy URL, not me. I get a correct URL using the driver. In the response of this correct URL there are some links (images for example) and _iframe_s that the driver try to download them and boom!

Comment: Could you paste your scraper code. Then I can tell you where to use the url parser function. You must have some sort of for link in links-loop, that ships the urls to the webdriver...

Comment: you have a variable - url - that you feed to requests five times in a row. Where should the content for the url come from?

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there...

```
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def google_play_download(app_page_id):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=" + app_page_id)
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block").click()
    time.sleep(10)

    apk_link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-success.btn-block").get_attribute('href')
    browser.quit()
    for rnd in range(5):
        resp = requests.get(apk_link)
        if resp.headers['Content-Length'] == str(len(resp.content)):
            return resp.content


if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = google_play_download("com.instagram.android")
    f = open('file.apk', 'wb')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Did you understand the question? The question is about a wrong protocol inside iframes of a page. Timeout won't do anything with the problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you run this code it'll download the apk you want... You just needed the right css selector to grab the id (the one saying something about success).

Comment: and then you needed a sleep as well. The site itself says the preparing the apk link could take up  to 3 minutes, so looking for the download url beforr it exists returns no download url. By the way you should consider changing the topic of the question as it never was a n iframe-issue. I have not been able to reproduce the error you initially posted. The code crashed when trying to pass the non existing variable, url, to requests.

Answer (score 0):

The parser is not able to extract the proper url in this line `apk_link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-success.btn-block").get_attribute('href')`

As when you print the url its showing `https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=com.instagram.android`

Just change the line to

```
apk_link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-success.btn-block")
ele=apk_link.get_attribute('href')

for rnd in range(5):
      resp = requests.get(ele)
      if resp.headers['Content-Length'] == str(len(resp.content)):
            return resp.content
```

The code will work without error